# Are all regular normal cones polyhedral? Or just coincidence?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I was studying a bit of constrained optimization in order to understand a [beautiful article](https://www.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/fileadmin/10040700/paper/PenDecomposition.pdf), and then a question raised:

> Are all the regular normal cones polyhedral ones?

This question has to do with the fact that, usually, to work with geometric optimality conditions involves simple type of cones.

If It is not true,

> What is the most important example of regular normal cone that is not a polyhedral cone?

Comment: No. Just take a non-polyhedral normal cone to a convex set. For such sets regular = 'standard' normal cone.

Comment: For example? Given a non-polyhedral cone, how can I construct a convex set whose normal cone is such a non-polyhedral set? That's my question.

Comment: Take the polar cone $C^0$ of the non-polyhedral cone $C$. Then its normal cone at zero is the original cone, $N_{C^0}(0) = C^{00} = C$.